# Not able to access custom input in collect method of AbstractTotal on clicking next first time but i can access it on second time

Tags: magento2, checkout, custom

I am learning magento , so I am trying to create a custom vat module that will allow users to validate vat and on success vat validation tax will be 0. I have added field on frontend checkout step to add input on clicking next I am not getting value of the field on first time " next " , but I get that value on clicking second time after coming back from checkout/#payment page..

Here is the code I have added so far this is my module.xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
        <module name="Mac_DiscountPlugin" setup_version="0.0.1">
            <sequence>
                <module name="Magento_Quote" />
                <module name="Magento_Checkout" />
            </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

This is the layout proccessor to add input field on checkout step

```
class LayoutProcessor
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array  $jsLayout
    ) {

        $customAttributeCode = 'save_vat_discount';
        $customField = [
            'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select',
            'config' => [
                'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/input',
            ],
            'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.save_vat_discount',
            'label' => 'Vat Code',
            'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
            'visible' => true,
            'validation' => ['required-entry' => false],
            'sortOrder' => 150,
        ];

        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children'][$customAttributeCode] = $customField;

        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

this is my mixin file

```
define(
    [
        'ko',
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/resource-url-manager',
        'mage/storage',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment-service',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/method-converter',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/error-processor'
    ],
    function (ko, $, quote, resourceUrlManager, storage, paymentService, methodConverter, errorProcessor) {
        'use strict';


        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).on('change', "[name='country_id']", function () {
                $("input:text[name='save_vat_discount']").parent('div').parent('div').hide();
                var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
                var valueSelected = this.value;
                if(valueSelected=='GB'){
                    $("input:text[name='save_vat_discount']").parent('div').parent('div').show();
                    $(document).on('blur', "input:text[name='save_vat_discount']", function () {
                        var vatcode = $(this).val();
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '/discountplugin/index/validationcall',
                            data:  {
                                'vatnumber':vatcode
                            },
                            type: "post",
                            cache: false,
                            success: function (data) {

                            }
                        });

                    });
                }else{
                    $("input:text[name='save_vat_discount']").parent('div').parent('div').hide();
                }
            });
        });





        return {
            saveShippingInformation: function() {
                var payload = {

                    addressInformation: {
                        shipping_address: quote.shippingAddress(),
                        shipping_method_code: quote.shippingMethod().method_code,
                        shipping_carrier_code: quote.shippingMethod().carrier_code,
                        extension_attributes: {
                            save_vat_discount: $('[name="save_vat_discount"]').val()
                        }
                    }
                };

                return storage.post(
                    resourceUrlManager.getUrlForSetShippingInformation(quote),
                    JSON.stringify(payload)
                ).done(
                    function (response) {
                        quote.setTotals(response.totals);
                        paymentService.setPaymentMethods(methodConverter(response.payment_methods));
                    }
                ).fail(
                    function (response) {
                        errorProcessor.process(response);
                    }
                );
            }
        };
    }
);
```

this is my extension_attributes.xml file

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Sales:etc/sales.xsd">
    <section name="quote">
        <group name="totals">
            <item name="sat_vat_discount" instance="Mac\DiscountPlugin\Model\DiscountCalculation" sort_order="500"/>
        </group>
    </section>
</config>
```

this is my di.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
       <plugin name="add_vat_discount_field" type="Mac\DiscountPlugin\Plugin\Checkout\LayoutProcessor" sortOrder="10"/>
   </type>
   <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement">
      <plugin name="save_to_quote_table" type="Mac\DiscountPlugin\Plugin\Checkout\SaveAddressInformation" sortOrder="10"/>
   </type>
   <type name="Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingAddressManagement">
      <plugin  name="shipping_management_custom" sortOrder="10" type="Mac\DiscountPlugin\Plugin\Checkout\ShippingAddressManagement"/>
   </type>
</config>
```

this is to store inout field to quote table

```
class SaveAddressInformation
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository
     */
    protected $quoteRepository;

    /**
     * SaveAddressInformation constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository $quoteRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository $quoteRepository
    ) {
        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement $subject
     * @param $cartId
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation
     */
    public function beforeSaveAddressInformation(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement $subject,
        $cartId,
        \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation
    ) {
        $extAttributes = $addressInformation->getExtensionAttributes();
        $discount = $extAttributes->getSaveVatDiscount();
        $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);
        $quote->setSaveVatDiscount($discount);

    }
}
```

and finally this is the collect() method where i am not getting vat discount input field value

```
class DiscountCalculation extends \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total\AbstractTotal
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Validator $validator,
        \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency
    )
    {
        $this->setCode('save_vat_discount');
        $this->eventManager = $eventManager;
        $this->calculator = $validator;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->priceCurrency = $priceCurrency;
    }

    public function collect(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
    ) {
        parent::collect($quote, $shippingAssignment, $total);
        $address             = $shippingAssignment->getShipping()->getAddress();
        $extAttributes = $address->getExtensionAttributes();

            $vatcode = $quote->getSaveVatDiscount();
            if(isset($tax) && $tax>0){
                $label               = 'Vat Discount';
                $discountAmount      = -$tax;

                $appliedCartDiscount = 0;
                if($total->getDiscountDescription()) {
                    // If a discount exists in cart and another discount is applied, the add both discounts.
                    $appliedCartDiscount = $total->getDiscountAmount();
                    $discountAmount      = $total->getDiscountAmount()+$discountAmount;
                    $label               = $total->getDiscountDescription().', '.$label;
                }

                $total->setDiscountDescription($label);
                $total->setDiscountAmount($discountAmount);
                $total->setBaseDiscountAmount($discountAmount);
                $total->setSubtotalWithDiscount($total->getSubtotal() + $discountAmount);
                $total->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount($total->getBaseSubtotal() + $discountAmount);

                if(isset($appliedCartDiscount)) {
                    $total->addTotalAmount($this->getCode(), $discountAmount - $appliedCartDiscount);
                    $total->addBaseTotalAmount($this->getCode(), $discountAmount - $appliedCartDiscount);
                } else {
                    $total->addTotalAmount($this->getCode(), $discountAmount);
                    $total->addBaseTotalAmount($this->getCode(), $discountAmount);
                }
            }

       /* }*/
        return $this;
    }

    public function fetch(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote, \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total)
    {
        $result = null;
        $amount = $total->getDiscountAmount();

        if ($amount != 0)
        {
            $description = $total->getDiscountDescription();
            $result = [
                'code' => $this->getCode(),
                'title' => 'Discountsdsssd',
                'value' => $amount
            ];
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

I am not getting $quote->getSaveVatDiscount() on first next click of checkout page .

Magento  2 .

Looking for your help friends .

Thanks in Advance